# Rails : get JS variable inside ruby inside inline js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I need to change some div content depending on the link the user clicked.
Here is my code

```
:javascript
  $('.some_clickable_item').on('click', function(e) {
    clicked_element_id=$(this).data("element_id")
    $('#my_destination_div').html("#{ render partial: "dashboard/some_partial_name", locals: {item_id: clicked_element_id} }");
  })
```

Obviously, this is not working because clicked_element_id is a js variable, but i need to pass it to my partial.

Any simple idea to make it work ?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendering of the partial happens *before* the `click` event. In fact, the partial is rendered on the server, before the browser receives a response.

You must use an XHR to replace the contents of `#my_destination_div`. See https://api.jquery.com/load/

> `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`
>
> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
>
> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server.
>
> https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Oh, i get it, i was being dumb. Thanks !